# Installing Redis on CentOS 6.6 , yum keeps using redis-2.8.14-2.el7.x86_64 (EL7) instead of EL6

Tags: centos, centos6, redis, centos6.6

Im trying to install redis on one of my servers.
but i keep getting

Error: Package: redis-2.8.14-2.el7.x86_64 (epel)
           Requires: systemd

This is due to the fact that its trying to download the centos 7 version.

i already removed the wrong repo but he keeps using it.

This is my repolist

```
repo id                                      repo name                                                                           status
base                                         CentOS-6 - Base                                                                     6518
epel                                         Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - x86_64                                      7410
extras                                       CentOS-6 - Extras                                                                     37
updates                                      CentOS-6 - Updates                                                                   830
```

i use this now:

```
wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm epel-release-6*.rpm
yum install redis
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You replaced the wrong EPEL repo (for CentOS 7) with the correct repo (for CentOS 6) but the system still is trying to download EPEL packages for 7.

In this case yum still has cached metadata from the EPEL repo from the last run with the wrong repo.

To resolve the problem, clear the cached metadata.

```
yum clean metadata
```